# Cordova iOS InAppBrowser options for location bar

Tags: ios, cordova, location, inappbrowser

The Cordova *InAppBrowser* plugin allows the developer to open the in application browser when a link is clicked. In the code it is initialized during the listener event:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", addInAppBrowser(), false);
```

where,

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    (void)addInAppBrowser = () => {
        window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(link, target: "_blank", browserOptions); 
    }
};
```

The *browserOptions* can be used to modify numerous aspects of the view, e.g. `closebuttoncolor` and `toolbar.`

Unfortunately, none of these options can be used to change the color of the location bar's `address.backgroundColor.`

Is it possible to change the attributes of the *addressLabel* during or after the initialization of the *InAppBrowser*, without having to modify the plugin code itself.

**Note: The code has been abbreviated for clarity.**

Answer (score 0):

### Update to Question with some Ideas

I did not find any *simple* method for implementing the functionality requested above. The InAppBrowser appears to only accept the designated options, which get parsed into an object and passed along through the code. Some ideas I had to get around this were:

- Using an after load callback to modify the plugin.
- Using hooks.

These are rather involved, and I suspect would take too much time to implement given the problem they were suppose to solve.

The application customer wanted to increase the contrast of the URL with the *view.backgroundColor*. They suggested a background color that would achieve the desired contrast. Since modifying the background color is not so straightforward, but it is simple to:

- Fork the *cordova-plugin-inappbrowser* and maintain the changes that will allow for fine control of the UI. The plugin is probably pretty stable, and so probably not problematic.

But I believe the correct solution will be to build a plugin that extends the InAppBrowser.